# Passing query string with input from a text box through a click PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass query string through a button and a text box.
Such that I enter some text into a text box and I will click an image button.
And that button will pass what is typed in the text box and pass it to next page.
How should I go about doing it?

Below is my code:

```
 <input type="text" name="search" class="resizedTextbox">
    <a href=page.php?productName=$_GET["search"]><img src="images/search-btn.gif"/></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<form method="GET" action="page.php">
<input type="text" name="search" class="resizedTextbox">
<input type="image" src="images/search-btn.gif"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<form name="frm" method="get" action="page.php">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/index.php?search='+document.getElementById('search').value;" id="btnSearch" class="buttonSearch" />
</form>
```

get value with java script and pass with get method.